# jscrollpane inside colorbox - bottom of iframe cut off?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, colorbox

I'm using colorbox to open an iframe, inside which i'm calling jscrollpane to allow scrolling. It works, but in some cases (not all, can't see a pattern) the lower maybe 100px or so are cut off. Further, I can't get scrollbars to appear on the ipad.

Any ideas?
http://www.ainonline.com/newsmakers/2011

Click on links in the timeline to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the pattern I am seeing is that the last block of text sometimes has a paragraph markup around it, and sometimes not, which happens to coincide with whether or not the text is shown entirely (*with* `<p>...</p>`) or some of the text stays hidden (*without* `<p>...</p>`).

Will not show the last bit of text:

```
<div class="articleview scrollpane" style="width:650px">
    <h1>Former Platinum Jet Pilot Gets Six Months Prison Time</h1>
    <div class="pubdate" style="color:#666; margin:10px 0; font-style:italic">August 23, 2011 - 3:20 PM</div>
    Blah blah blah [...] blah.
</div>
```

Will show the last bit of text:

```
<div class="articleview scrollpane" style="width:650px">
    <h1>Former Platinum Jet Pilot Gets Six Months Prison Time</h1>
    <div class="pubdate" style="color:#666; margin:10px 0; font-style:italic">August 23, 2011 - 3:20 PM</div>
    <p>Blah blah blah [...] blah.</p>
</div>
```

Let me know if this solves that problem.

For the other part of the question (which really should be asked in a separate question), the iPad does not use scrollbars on websites.  It uses gestures.  Don't worry about it, though -- the site works great.

Comment: Of course! We just migrated from an old CMS a few months back, and many old content is missing <p> tags, using line breaks instead.  I edited a few that were getting cut off and replaced the breaks with paragraphs and we're good to go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here the pages you are loading have a 8px margin on the body (user agent stylesheet), which results the pages are a bit off to the right and bottom. Then it looks like you are missing parts of the pages.

Put margin: 0px; on the body element like:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On every page included via iframe you must ensure you explicitly state the margin of the body like so:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

If you don't do this the browser will use it's default settings and this means different results from different browsers also.

You should check out: [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)

It is a stylesheet designed to reset all browsers to the same standard styling rules.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem ... This was my solution

```
$(".gallery").colorbox({
            iframe:true,
            fastIframe:false,
            width:"630px",
            height:"555px",
            scrolling: false,
            rel:'gallery', 
            slideshow:false, 
            onComplete:function(){ $(".cboxIframe").contents().find("body").css("margin","0px");
                //$("#banner").insertBefore("#cboxLoadedContent")
            }
        });
```